# Replacing (escaping) characters in Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

For a gradle script, I am composing strings that will be used as command line for a subsequent gradle Test-task. One of the strings is the user's password, which eventually will be passed to the called (exec'ed) "java ..." call using the JVM's `-D`  option, e.g. `-Dpassword=foobar`.

What complicates things here is, that this password can/should of course contain special characters, that may interfere with the use of the string as command line. In other words: I need to escape special characters (which is OS-specific). :-(

**Now to my actual question:** 
I want to use the `String.replaceAll` method, i.e. `replaceAll(list_of_special characters, EscapeCharacter + Ref_to_matched_character)`,

e.g. simplified something like `replaceAll("[#$%^&]", "^$1")`

`'^'` meaning the escape character and `'$1'` meaning the matched character here.

**Is that possible, i.e. can one refer to the matched pattern in the second argument of replaceAll?**

Comment: How do you run/use those flags exactly?  Most likely params will be passed to processes directly and are OS agnostic (unless you fork off a shell)

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible, i.e. can one refer to the matched pattern in the second argument of replaceAll?

yes, it's possible

```
'a#b$c'.replaceAll('([#$%^&])', '^$1')
```

returns

```
a^#b^$c
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses and the reviews improving readability. Meanwhile I got my expression working. For those interested:

```
// handles gthe following: `~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:;"'<>?,./
escaped = original.replaceAll('[~!@#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)_\\+-={}\\|\\[\\]\\\\:;\"\\\'<>\\?,\\./]', '^$0') // for Windows - cmd.exe
```